# Factoring out a while loop in SQL script

Tags: sql, refactoring

Suppose I have a table amountInfo with columns (id, amount1, amount2, amount3)
where amountX are money values and id is an int value ranging from 1 to some int under 10.

Currently I have some code that approximately does this:

```
declare @id int, @idmax int, @amounttotal money
select @idmax = (select max(Id) from amountInfo)
while (@id <= @idmax)
begin
    select @amounttotal = sum(amount1 + amount2 + amount3) 
                          from amountinfo where id=@id
    -- do something with @amounttotal
    select @id=@id+1
end
```

Is there a way to factor out the while loop with some kind of complex select statement here? I am experienced with C/C++/C# programming but SQL is kinda new to me. Thanks!

EDIT: basically the "--do something" part involves inserting the individual @amounttotals into another table. The actual query I'm running is more complicated than that but I'm hoping to solve this simple problem first before posting a huge example of code.

Comment: I have an idea but I'm concerned it would be conditional on what *do something with @amounttotal* is...  Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: I agree with Austin... what you are trying to do will drive what the answer to your question is. If you are trying to update or insert other records, you probably just need to use a subquery. Also, is ID going to correspond to a number of rows, or just always 1 row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable
        (id, col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT 
        dt.id, t.col1, dt.TotalSum
        FROM (SELECT
                  id, SUM(t.amount1 + t.amount2 + t.amount3) AS TotalSum
                  FROM AMOUNTINFO
                  GROUP BY id
                  WHERE id>=@id AND id<=@idmax
             ) dt
            INNER JOIN  AMOUNTINFO t ON dt.id=t.id
```

Comment: This looks good, but shouldn't the comparison in the where clause be "id>=@id AND id < @idmax"?

Comment: @Garett: The original while loop had <= so I think that's right in the where clause. Being picky, I'd take the ',...' out of the answer as it's not matching the select. Otherwise, still giving it +1, looks like the right idea.

Comment: @Jim. Yes you're right. I noticed the instructions said "ranging from 1 to some int under 10", but I didn't pay attention to the original loop.

Comment: Thanks KM, this is the beginnings of what I need to solve my real problems: the nested selects and group by clause are the key.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the WHILE loop, use:

```
SELECT @amounttotal = SUM(t.amount1 + t.amount2 + t.amount3)
  FROM AMOUNTINFO t
 WHERE t.id BETWEEN @id AND @idmax
```

...but you need to describe what you're doing in the WHILE loop to the `@amounttotal` variable for us to help you further.

Comment: but how does this address `-- do something with @amounttotal`??  The "do something" could be just about anything: call a stored procedure, UPDATE tableX, etc.???  This answer is clearly not what the original loop is doing. BTW, nice new picture, you might need taller boots though ;-)

Comment: @KM, Right I need the individual totals from each row, getting the entire sum is not what I want